# Prestashop 1.7 custom module front controller doesn't work

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Trying to create a front controller module that has a strange behaviour
Using the `$link->getModuleLink('vpages', 'dpage', $params)` in the tpl page, the URL will be correctly presented as `mysite.com/en/40-flower-delivery-Andorra.html`. When trying to access the page, I will be provided with a 404 page and the url will become `mysite.com/en/index.php?controller=dpage&id_country=40&country=Andorra&module=vpages`

if I manually alter the url by adding the `&fc=module`, I will get a 500 Internal error page

The module has the following script:

```
<?php

class vPages extends Module
{
    private $html = '';
    private $postErrors = array();
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'vpages';
        $this->tab = 'others';
        $this->version = '1.0';
        $this->author = 'Rosu Andrei Mihai';
        $this->is_eu_compatible = 1;
        $this->need_instance = 1;
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->controllers = array('dpage');

        $this->displayName = $this->l('vPages');
        $this->description = $this->l('Virtual dynamic pages');
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to delete all saved details?');
        $this->secure_key = Tools::encrypt($this->name);
        
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function install()
    {
        return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('moduleRoutes');
    }

    public function hookModuleRoutes($params){
        $my_link = array(
            'module-vpages-dpage' => array(
                'controller' => 'dpage',
                'rule' => '{id_country:-}flower-delivery{-:country}{-:city}.html',
                'keywords' => array(
                    'id_country' => array('regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'id_country'),
                    'setCountry' => array('regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'setCountry'),
                    'country' => array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9\pL\pS]+', 'param' => 'country'),
                    'city' => array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9\w\pL\pS-]*', 'param' => 'city'),
                    'module_action' => array('regexp' => '[\w]+', 'param' => 'module_action')
                ),
                'params' => array(
                    'fc' => 'module',
                    'module' => 'vpages'
                )
                )
            );
        return $my_link;
    }

    
    public function uninstall()
    {
        if (!parent::uninstall()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The front controller has the following script:

```
<?php

class vpagesdpageModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public $errors = array();
    public $display_column_left = false;
    public $display_column_right = false;
    public $ssl = true;
    public $php_self = 'dpage'; 

        
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->page_name = 'dpage';
        $this->context = Context::getContext();
    }

    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
        
        $this->context->cookie->__set('productbycountry_id',Tools::getValue('id_country')); 
        $sql     = "SELECT DISTINCT ps_country_lang.id_country, ps_country_lang.name as country, city FROM ps_cms_target_world
                    LEFT JOIN ps_country_lang ON ps_cms_target_world.id_country = ps_country_lang.id_country
                    WHERE ps_country_lang.id_country=" . Tools::getValue('id_country') . "
                    ORDER BY country ASC";
        //die($sql);
        $cPages  = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);                
        
        $get_url  = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('SELECT domain,physical_uri FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'shop_url ');
        $protocol = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") ;
        $site_url = "$protocol://".$get_url[0]['domain'].$get_url[0]['physical_uri']."modules";

        $controller_url = $this->context->link->getModuleLink('vpages', 'vPagesController', array(), true);
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'link' => $this->context->link,
            'controller_url' => $controller_url,
            'cPages' => $cPages,
            'SITEURL' => $site_url
        ));
        
        $country = urldecode(Tools::getValue('country'));        
        $city = urldecode(Tools::getValue('city'));
        if(isset($city) && !empty($city)) $title = " - " . $city; 
        
        $this->context->smarty->assign('meta_title', 'Flower delivery to ' . $country . $title);
        
        $this->setTemplate('module:vpages/views/templates/front/dPage.tpl');
    }


}
```

In the tpl file, I generate the friendly url using the following script:

```
{foreach $vPages as $page}
    <div class="country_content col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 center-block text-center">
        <p>
        {assign var=params value=[
            'module_action' => 'list',
            'id_country'=> $page.id_country,
            'setCountry'=> $page.id_country,
            'country'=> urlencode($page.country),
            'city' => null
        ]}
        {assign var="meta_title" value="Flowers to {$page.country}"}
        
            <a style="color:normal" href="{$link->getModuleLink('vpages', 'dpage', $params)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$meta_title|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                <img width="98" height="70" src="{$SITEURL}/vpages/flags/{$page.country}.png" style="padding-right: 3px; margin=bottom: 5px;" />
                <br />
                <p>{$page.country|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</p>
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
{/foreach}
```

I don't get what is wrong in the code, in PS 1.6 the code works perfect in PS 1.7 it doesn't
Could someone point me to the mistake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The link should be created in your module's class not in the tpl, a tpl is just for layout.
Use this in your class `$this->context->link->getModuleLink('your_module_name', 'ajax', [], null, null, null, true)`
Then assign it with smarty to your tpl.

Comment: I updated my question, in reply to your comment, thank you!

Comment: what is changed, you still  retrieve the link in your tpl...

Comment: I didn't said I changed the script, I only updated my question. And the link can be generated directly in the tpl file